# Substituting one series in another provided that the values of the substituted series are in the circle of convergence of the other series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

From Boas, under theorems about Power Series. This theorem is presented without an example (or proof), and I cannot exactly understand the notion of substituting one series into another one. It is probably a misunderstanding.

**Theorem** One series may be substituted in another provided that the values of the substituted series are in the circle of convergence of the other series.

I mean, would the wording

"Two series are interchangeable as long as their intervals of convergence coincide" be describing the same result?

Comment: No. It's about putting $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ as the argument into $g(w) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_kw^k$ to get $$g(f(z)) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n\right)^k = b_0 + b_1(a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \dotsb) + b_2(a_1z + a_2z^2 + \dotsb)^2 + \dotsb = b_0 + b_1a_1 z + (b_1a_2 + b_2a_1^2)z^2 + \dotsb$$

Comment: That clarified it. Thanks!